# Translate SQL UPDATE with multiple INNER JOIN and WHERE into PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to execute the below code using PySpark:

```py
join_on = (df_1.C1_PROFIT == df_2.C2_PROFIT) & \            # JOIN CONDITION
          (df_1.C1_REVENUE == df_3.C3_REVENUE_BREAK) & \    # JOIN CONDITION
          (df_1.C1_LOSS == df_4.C4_TOTAL_LOSS) & \          # JOIN CONDITION
          ((df_4.TOTAL_YEAR_PROFIT) > (df_3.TOTAL_GROWTH))  # WHERE CONDITION
df = (df_1.alias('a')
    .join(df_2.alias('b'), join_on, 'left')
    .join(df_3.alias('c'), join_on, 'left')
    .join(df_4.alias('d'), join_on, 'left')
    .select(
        *[c for c in df_2.columns if c != 'C2_TARGET'],
        F.expr("nvl2(b.C2_PROFIT, '500', a.C2_TARGET) C2_TARGET")
    )
)
```

Error after running the query:

> 'TOTAL_YEAR_PROFIT','TOTAL_GROWTH', 'TOTAL_LOSS', 'REVENUE_BREAK'
> does not exist in df_1 columns:

The original SQL query:

```sql
UPDATE (( companyc1
          INNER JOIN companyc2
                  ON company1.c1_profit = company2.c2_profit)
        INNER JOIN companyc3
                ON company1.c1_revenue = company3.revenue_break)
       INNER JOIN companyc4
               ON company1.c1_loss = company4.c4_total_loss
SET    companyc1.sales = "500"
WHERE  (( ( company4.total_year_profit ) > [company3].[total_growth] ))
```

Can anyone help me find where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: Has any answer helped to solve the problem?

Comment: no @ZygD, i have splitted all the joins and that is working, 
like [df2= df.join((broadcast(df1), on =[], how =left]
df3= df2.join(df4, on=[], how='left'

Comment: You should post it as a separate answer, so that noone would try to answer if you already have what works for you and so that others would find your answer easier when they need such solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `join_on` conditions will have to be split for each of the `join` operation, like so:

```py
df = (df_1.alias('a')
    .join(df_2.alias('b'), df_1.C1_PROFIT == df_2.C2_PROFIT, 'left')
    .join(df_3.alias('c'), df_1.C1_REVENUE == df_3.C3_REVENUE_BREAK, 'left')
    .join(df_4.alias('d'), df_1.C1_LOSS == df_4.C4_TOTAL_LOSS. 'left')
    .select(
        *[c for c in df_2.columns if c != 'C2_TARGET'],
        F.expr("nvl2(b.C2_PROFIT, '500', a.C2_TARGET) C2_TARGET")
    ).where("d.TOTAL_YEAR_PROFIT > c.TOTAL_GROWTH")
)
```

Comment: The `where` method accepts SQL expressions, so you should be able to do it like this: `company4.total_year_profit > company3.total_growth AND company1.Quartergrowth IS NULL AND company2.Quarter2Growth IS NOT NULL`. If you don't want to use SQL expression, then you could something like this: `where((col("company4.total_year_profit") > col("company3.total_growth")) & (col("company1.Quartergrowth").isNull()) & (col("company2.Quarter2Growth").isNotNull()))`

Comment: hi @Bartosz Gajda, i try to implement the code it is generating correct result but one issue is coming in our final output file it is giving less rows in df_1 around 1000 but i have 500000 rows in my df_1, i am using left join here so that it will take all data from df_1 but in output it is returning only 1000 rows

Comment: df_4 = (df1.alias('a')
.join(df2.alias('b'), df1.State == df2.state_region, 'left')
.select(
*[c for c in df_1.columns if c != 'FLAG'],
F.expr("nvl2(b.state_region, b.FLAG_VALUE, a.FLAG) FLAG")
).where((df2.STATUS == 1) & (df2.structure.isNull()) & (df2.Program_status.isNotNull())))

Comment: I think the where condition at the last is taking only filtered data

Answer (score 0):

When translating SQL `UPDATE` containing multiple joins, it seems to me, that the universally safe approach could involve `groupBy`, `agg` and `monotonically_increasing_id` (to make sure that the row number of the original df will not shrink after the aggregation).

I've made the following tables in MS Access, to make sure that the approach I suggest, would work the same way in Spark.

**Inputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Result after the update:**

[image]

---

**Spark**

It seems, MS Access aggregates column values, so the following will do the same.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(2,   10,    5, 'replace'),
     (2,   10,    5, 'replace'),
     (1,   10, None,    'keep'),
     (2, None,    5,    'keep')],
    ['C1_PROFIT', 'C1_REVENUE', 'C1_LOSS', 'SALES']
)
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (8,)], ['C2_PROFIT'])
df_3 = spark.createDataFrame([(10, 51), (10, 50)], ['REVENUE_BREAK', 'TOTAL_GROWTH'])
df_4 = spark.createDataFrame([(5, 50), (5, 51),], ['C4_TOTAL_LOSS', 'TOTAL_YEAR_PROFIT'])
```

Script:

```py
df_1 = df_1.withColumn('_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = (df_1.alias('a')
    .join(df_2.alias('b'), df_1.C1_PROFIT == df_2.C2_PROFIT, 'left')
    .join(df_3.alias('c'), df_1.C1_REVENUE == df_3.REVENUE_BREAK, 'left')
    .join(df_4.alias('d'), df_1.C1_LOSS == df_4.C4_TOTAL_LOSS, 'left')
    .groupBy(*[c for c in df_1.columns if c != 'SALES'])
    .agg(F.when(F.max('d.total_year_profit') > F.min('c.total_growth'), '500')
          .otherwise(F.first('a.SALES')).alias('SALES')
    ).drop('_id')
)
df.show()
# +---------+----------+-------+-----+
# |C1_PROFIT|C1_REVENUE|C1_LOSS|SALES|
# +---------+----------+-------+-----+
# |        1|        10|   null| keep|
# |        2|      null|      5| keep|
# |        2|        10|      5|  500|
# |        2|        10|      5|  500|
# +---------+----------+-------+-----+
```